# Pytest very slow depending on the Wifi connection

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have a very strange problem none of my other dev coworkers have within the same codebase.

My pytest suite takes about 2min while it's collecting tests, once the first test runs it runs at normal speed through them all.

For other devs, this 2 min wait is not existent, it collect the tests and runs them in about the same amount of time once it starts.

Even stranger is if I'm connected to my phone hotspot (and one other wifi network from a certain office), this 2 min wait is not there and pytest collects and runs test at the same speed as other devs. Under any other Wifi network or no wifi connection at all, it hangs.

None of our tests require internet connection so I'm at a loss what to try, I wasn't able to find similar posts online so I thought of asking here.

I have updated pytest version to the latest version plus re-installed my whole dev environment to no avail.  I've also tried running pytest with different flags but so far nothing changes or yields information about the cause for this.

Im on a Macbook M1 13" 8Gb Ram.    (Other devs on M1 don't have this problem btw only me).  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you have no wifi connection? Does running pytest with `--verbose` give any additional information?

Comment: Since the project name is `api` I assume you are using `requests` to connect to an API? this can be effected by a bad internet connection.

Comment: I see the plugin for celery, Check what backend is configured. Is the backend running locally or on some other machine. Check your environment variables to see whether you configured a remote backend there.

Comment: @tsnowlan thanks, --verbose doesn't say anything while it's waiting or 2 minutes, only after the test start running unfortunately.

Sebastian Stigler - The backend is running locally.

Comment: Can you try installing your environment in another location on you machine?

Comment: @JasonCook Thanks, yes already did but unfortunately no change.

Comment: @Carl Sala I agree with Guy, Could you have a look at the tests which has failed when the testing hangs for two minutes? It looks like the test needs an internet connection and waits for some time until stop the connection and assert the test fails.